# How to read a push notification with an app in the background?

Tags: delphi, service, notifications, push

I'm using Delphi 10.4.2 to make an app for Android. I need a routine to run when a push notification arrives, but without the user needing to touch the push.

I've already found some examples here, but all of them are in Java, but it didn't solve my issue because Delphi is very different.

I was able to do this but only when the app is in the foreground. I believe the solution is to use a service to do this, but I couldn't get the service to read the push load. I also tried using a broadcast receiver, but it seems that nothing can interact with the push when in the background.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: I'm not an Android dev, but IIRC apps are suspended when they are in the background, so a service is the way to go.

Comment: Embarcadero hasn't yet provided support for (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler). This is because one needs to inherit from a Java Class which Embarcadero doesn't support. You can't just use Java2pas or Jave2op for this. Before Android 6, it was possible to use a foreground service with a wakelock, but this doesn't work on later versions of Android.

Comment: "I couldn't get the service to read the push load". Can you provide an example of how you were doing this? I've implemented something that may be what you are after, which extends [this code](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Playground/tree/main/Demos/FCMRebooted), however I've only just done so and am yet to make it public. I am curious as to what you want to do with the push information though - there may be an alternative, depending on your answer.

Comment: I'm developing a system to control aquariums, through the app (for Android and IOS) the user can do some actions like treating the fish.
  The problem is exactly in the alarms, water temperature for example, the only way I found to transfer the information from the server to the app is the push notification. As some of these messages require attention and immediate action from the user, I thought of leaving a service to play a sound when receiving notifications, such as a siren for example, to draw the user's attention.
Another alternative would be very welcome too.

Comment: Sounds can already be associated with push notifications (they are assigned to a channel). On Android, Embarcadero are yet to implement this, however it can be done with custom code. As a guide, you could examine the `TNotificationCenterAndroid.CreateChannel` method in the `System.Android.Notification` unit in Delphi (what it is missing is `setSound`). I thought I had a clear example of how to do this - I'll come up with one later

Comment: Unfortunately Embarcadero has been lacking in its integration with Android, there are a lot of loose ends.
I had already studied these documents, after two days of trying I couldn't implement setSound, that makes me wonder if it wouldn't be better to make the app in Android Studio.